# Запятые в предложениях

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, синтаксис

Объясните, пожалуйста, каждую запятую в предложениях. Каждая 100% стоит правильно.

*На протяжении всей истории человечества считалось, что мир делится на тех, кто правит, и на тех, кем правят, и что если находишься в одной категории, то уже нельзя перейти в другую.*

*Когда таял снег в степи или проливался хороший ливневый дождь, от глины, которую смывало со склонов и холмов, вода долго бывала красной.*

Comment: Ну вы сами попробуйте объяснить, а мы поправим. Здесь не решают дз, но помогают

Comment: @Илья Вообще-то первое предложение у автора выглядит так: *На протяжении всей истории человечества считалось, что мир делится на тех, кто правит, и на тех, кем правят, и что, находясь в одной категории, нельзя перейти в другую.* (https://www.litres.ru/radislav-gandapas/harizma-lidera/chitat-onlayn/)